# The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk:

Tags: usb, dvd, cd

I got this error during installation.

> The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk:
> [Errno 5] Input/output error This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk
> or drive, or a faulty hard disk. It may help to clean the CD/DVD, to
> burn the CD/DVD at a lower speed, to clean the CD/DVD drive lens
> (cleaning kits are often available from electronics suppliers), to
> check whether the hard disk is old and in need of replacement, or to
> move the system to a cooler environment.

How can I fix this and what does it mean specifically? I'm installing via USB so it can't be the CD. the laptop is recent so it cant be an old HD.

Comment: The CD refers to your installation media (ie. errors on your USB device).  You haven't said release, but did you verify the ISO? prior to write to media, and then validate the write to your media? (ie. the USB device).  CD I/O errors imply you didn't or errors occurred during one of both of those steps (the write to USB media I find the most at fault).  Release here matters, as the methods of validation of media vary on release, but https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 applies to all

Comment: Take note in particular of my **not upvoted** answer... It'll be the better for you.. Had you raised a bug report, you'll have I bet got a response like I mention there..   (*that answer was from another question that was being deleted...  moved there as I often find questions like this that I find worthwhile referring people to*)  You didn't do the checks before hand I bet, so it provides the checks you can use to confirm what I'm saying on your actual system :)

Comment: What it means "*specifically*" is a prior step in the installation was faulty.  Either your ISO was invalid (did you verify it as per documented instructions?) or the write the install media was invalid (did you verify that?  that step is optional for some releases, automatic on others, but you didn't provide release details..)   You can switch to a text terminal & confirm the issue as I've already stated (*see answer in provided link I've alluded too*), but the cause is a caused by bad-luck & skipping validation steps (*taking a risk to save time but it didn't work out for you*..)